# Ошибка Call to undefined function query()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Пытаюсь выполнить код

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$database = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
                or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($connect));

mysqli_close($connect);

$query ="SELECT name FROM 'my_table'";
$result = query($connect) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($connect)); //line 13
if($result)
{
    echo "Выполнение запроса прошло успешно";
}

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Получаю ответ

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function query() in C:\Users\Vit\PhpstormProjects\untitled\index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Vit\PhpstormProjects\untitled\index.php on line 13**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

query поменяйте на mysqli_query()

http://www.php.su/mysqli_query

Comment: делал вот так $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) и получаю ошибку Warning: mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Users\Vit\PhpstormProjects\untitled\index.php on line 13
Ошибка

Comment: $query ="SELECT name FROM `my_table`"; - неправильные кавычки были указаны, укажите или без кавычек или косые `

Comment: А так же не mysqli_query($connect) а mysqli_query($query)

Comment: всё равно та же ошибка..может ещё в коде неправильные где то ковычки? теперь ещё такая ошибка Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Users\Vit\PhpstormProjects\untitled\index.php on line 13

Comment: И перед выполнением запроса уберите mysqli_close($connect);
 )Вы же закрыли соединение и пытаетесь выполнить запрос

Comment: отлично..сработало!  а косые кавычки только в запросе нужно ж использовать? верно?

Comment: Да, В них заключают имена столбцов и  таблиц  ... . Тогда не будет ошибки, если имя является зарезервированным словом, состоит из нескольких слов, разных символов и так далее

Comment: спасибо! понял!